# How I can input some animation calculating for the number?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this script and I want to input some ***animation*** for the number, but I don't know how to resolved that.

```js
 $('#choose').change(function() {
      if($(this).val() == '1') {
        document.getElementById('harga').innerHTML = "5000";
      }  
      if($(this).val() == '2') {
        document.getElementById('harga').innerHTML = "10000";
      }  
      if($(this).val() == '3') {
        document.getElementById('harga').innerHTML = "30000";
      }
})
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <div class="harga" id="harga"> 5000 </div>
    <select id="choose">
      <option value="1">choose 1</option>
      <option value="2">choose 2</option>
      <option value="3">choose 3</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: can you clarify what `some animation` could possibly be

Comment: Do you mean you want the user to see the `harga` element's value count up or down from its current value to the new value, like a digital clock that has been sped up? (If so, how long do you want the animation to take? What if the user selects another value before the previous animation finishes?) Hint: a `setTimeout()`-based pseudo loop is the simplest way to implement something like that.

Comment: can you write the script, I still confused what do you direct for.

Comment: What is the expectation. You need to make clear.http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant the animation as counter number down or up,

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="harga" id="harga"> 5000 </div>
<select id="choose">
  <option value="1">choose 1</option>
  <option value="2">choose 2</option>
  <option value="3">choose 3</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
var options = {"1":5000,"2":10000,"3":30000,}
var amount = options["1"]; //default

$('#choose').change(function() {
  selected_amount = options[$(this).val()];

  $({ Counter: amount }).animate({ Counter: selected_amount }, {
    duration: 1000, //speed
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function () {
      $('#harga').text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
    },
    complete: function(){
      $('#harga').text(selected_amount);
      amount = selected_amount;
    }
  });  
 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#choose').change(function() {
  if($(this).val() == '1') {
    document.getElementById('harga').innerHTML = "5000";
  }  
  if($(this).val() == '2') {
    document.getElementById('harga').innerHTML = "10000";
  }  
  if($(this).val() == '3') {
    document.getElementById('harga').innerHTML = "30000";
  }
})
</script>
```

You can put the following to make it fadeout first, then fade in using basic jquery. Otherwise you may use [Animate CSS](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

```
$("#harga").fadeOut(400,function(){
  $(this).html("5000").fadeIn();  
});

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#choose').change(function() {
  if($(this).val() == '1') {

    $("#harga").fadeout(400,function(){
        $(this).html("5000").fadein();
    });
    //document.getElementById('harga').innerHTML = "5000";
  }  
  if($(this).val() == '2') {
    document.getElementById('harga').innerHTML = "10000";
  }  
  if($(this).val() == '3') {
    document.getElementById('harga').innerHTML = "30000";
  }
})
</script>
```

and so on... hope it helps